# Will Data migration tool delete my M1.9 database while migrating to M2.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

My M1.9 site is still live and I am building a new M2.x site so I need to migrate my data to the new site.
I wonder whether my M1.9 database will be gone after migration, do I need to back up it using this tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer If you find It helpful @Billy

Answer (score 0):

No, `Magento 1` database will remain same as before, data migration tool only migrate data nothing else. And If you don't have data backup before any operation then It is going to like [this](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/0b/0b579741aa14f4769dc02768fefda4c54e22755745c3757ec0d39f7efc087f36.jpg)

Also, please try first in your staging environment Instead of live environment. Further more you can read more about this from this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html)